# How to change the skintone with OpenGl + mediapipe aar android

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, texture-mapping, mediapipe

i'm using mediapipe aar in android and using opengl to fill the color in particular **landmarks (lips).**

Problem is its not looking realistic or some good looking.

as of my analysis, **TextureFrame** applying in the **GLSurfaceView** with vertex and Fragment shader, and whatever I'm applying polygons(Triangles) in another program(vertex and fragment)

- I tried to use mix in fragment shader - not worked.(because camera texture frame in another program(vertex and fragment shader), and the color apply in particular coordinates is in another program)

How can i get the particular pixel(texture or texel) and apply the color mix to achieve some realistic thing.?
or is any other approaches there?

Update :
I'm using Solutions API from Mediapipe
I'm changing the this [FaceMeshResultGlRenderer.java](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/examples/android/solutions/facemesh/src/main/java/com/google/mediapipe/examples/facemesh/FaceMeshResultGlRenderer.java) Renderer file to do polygons works.

changed drawLandmarks function as below,

```
 val vertex: FloatArray = FloatArray(connections.size * 4) //connections are array list for my facemesh landmarks in triangle.

    var lastAddedIndex = 0

    for (i in 0 until connections.size) {
        val starts: LandmarkProto.NormalizedLandmark = faceLandmarkList[connections[i].start]
        val ends: LandmarkProto.NormalizedLandmark = faceLandmarkList[connections[i].end]
        vertex[lastAddedIndex++] = starts.x
        vertex[lastAddedIndex++] = starts.y
        vertex[lastAddedIndex++] = ends.x
        vertex[lastAddedIndex++] = ends.y
    }

    val vertexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertex.size * 4)
        .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
        .asFloatBuffer()
        .put(vertex)
    vertexBuffer.position(0)

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle)
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexBuffer)
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, (vertex.size / 2))
```

and my **fragment shader** and rest of the code is same in above **FaceMeshResultGlRenderer.java** file

below is my current output.
[image]

Comment: Not experienced with Mediapipe, but after reading: https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/face_mesh and https://google.github.io/mediapipe/framework_concepts/gpu.html#gpubuffer-to-imageframe-converters I'm leaning toward you'll have to create your own [mediapipe calculator function](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/framework_concepts/calculators.html) which can process the source image and the mesh (basically custom mediapipe).

Comment: @MorrisonChang Hi, actually I'm using thier solutions api, in that we can directly draw the things using openGl. so, can you please confirm if possible whether it only possible by custom calculator or can we achieve in openGl. I'm trying with OpenGl right now, if there is no possible i will look into calculator functions.(seems c++ opencv also they used, thatsway i'm trying with opengl es in android)

Comment: You may want to show some code/snippets as to how you are integrating your fragment shader. If your code is based off a existing sample/example do show what you've changed.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Hi, updated the question with code snippets, can you check now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make Opengl Color Overlay realistic look in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74937273/how-to-make-opengl-color-overlay-realistic-look-in-android)

Comment: This is a duplicate of your earlier question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74937273/how-to-make-opengl-color-overlay-realistic-look-in-android Please don't post the same quesition twice. If the first one needs improving then edit it.

Comment: @solidpixel Hi, sorry i didn't get proper response for that. now i deleted that post. Thanks